# How to export Matlab Bathtub Curve to excel? In Matlab R2021.b

Tags: excel, matlab

I wish to convert my Bathtub graph to data form, and plot it in excel.
Can anyone advice me how to export this graph data to excel? Thank you.

[Matlab Bathtub curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSrzn.png)

Below is my Matlab code (in R2021b version):

```
Fs = 10000;             
Rs = 100;               
sps = Fs/Rs;            
SNR = 30;              
Trise = 1/(5*Rs);      
Tfall = 1/(5*Rs);       
frameLen = 5000;        
Tx = commsrc.pattern('SamplingFrequency', Fs, 'SamplesPerSymbol', sps, 'RiseTime', Trise, 'FallTime', Tfall);
Tx.Jitter = commsrc.combinedjitter('SamplingFrequency', Fs);
Tx.Jitter.DiracJitter = 'on'; 
Tx.Jitter.DiracDelta = 0.5e-3*[-1 1];
Tx.Jitter.RandomJitter = 'on';
Tx.Jitter.RandomStd = 0.3e-3;
message = generate(Tx, frameLen);
channel = comm.AWGNChannel('NoiseMethod','Signal to noise ratio (SNR)','SNR', SNR, 'SignalPower', 1);
Rx = channel(message);
eyeObj = comm.EyeDiagram('YLimits', [-1.5 1.5],'SamplesPerSymbol', sps,'SampleRate', Fs, 'SampleOffset', 0.004*Fs,'DisplayMode', '2D color histogram','ColorScale', 'Logarithmic');
eyeObj.EnableMeasurements = true;
eyeObj.OverlayHistogram = 'Jitter';
eyeObj.ShowBathtub = 'Horizontal';
eyeObj(Rx);
show(eyeObj);
```

Comment: Is it necessary for you to export data to Excel and plot it again? Can you not export the image directly?

Comment: Actually I wish to compare 3 bathtub curve in one graph, and this the reason why i wish to export the figure data to excel. Btw, at the end i use WebPlotDigitizer to convert the grapg png to data.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to export the figure to excel: [link to github repo](https://github.com/michellehirsch/xlswritefig)

Comment: The author of the question wants to export the data of his graph and plot it in excel.